# check parameters type before run route in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have 2 kind on route.

like this:

You know for these:

```
Route::get('/{category_slug}/{article_slug}', 'mController@list');

Route::get('/{category_slug}/{subcategory_slug?}', 'mController@clist');
```

It run only first route.

I try binding them in **RouteServiceProvider** boot(){

```
Route::bind('category_slug', function ($category_slug, $route) {dd('category_slug') }); //works

Route::bind('article_slug', function ($article_slug, $route) { dd('article_slug') }); //works for both article_slug(ok!) and subcategory_slug(wrong!)

Route::bind('subcategory_slug', function ($subcategory_slug, $route) { dd('subcategory_slug') }); //not works
```

}

Is there a way to check {article_slug} or {subcategory_slug} before loading route and then system choosing right route? for example if first is wrong, then skip it and try to run second route.

for example middleware can do that?

Comment: The parameters are only placeholders and you can't really use them to redirect the routes to controllers. Can you not use another route instead?

Comment: @pseudoanime I want create like this URL: `example.com/cat/subcat1_slug/subcat2_slug.../subcatN_slug/article_slug` ... I hourly search google and I couldn't find a solution. So I think maybe I could do via the top way...

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel slugs are unique per table not unique throughout all tables. I would recommend using something like a keyword to determine what slug is expected. This is way more efficient and cleaner then querying to determine if the slug is of an type `article` or `category` of object.

```
Route::get('/{category_slug}/', 'mController@clist');
Route::get('/{category_slug}/sub/{subcategory_slug}', 'mController@clist');
Route::get('/{category_slug}/sub/{subcategory_slug}/{article_slug}', 'mController@list');
Route::get('/{category_slug}/{article_slug}', 'mController@list');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different url or different method of request in order to fulfil your demand.

Like -

```
Route::get('/{category_slug}/{article_slug}', 'mController@list');
Route::post('/{category_slug}/{subcategory_slug?}', 'mController@clist');
```

Use `Route::update()` if need to modify a data which is already in database or `Request::delete()` to delete a data in the database.

Or like the answer of [tprj29](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47596021/6349060) you need to use different kinds of url